# Finding a context-sensitive grammar for L

Tags: formal-grammar

I need help for finding a context-sensitive grammar for the following language:
$$
L = \left\{ ww \left| w \in \left\{a, b\right\}^* \right. \right\}
$$
Would that be a correct context-sensitive grammar?
S  -> ε | AUAV | BUBV   (1)
U -> AUC | BUD          (2)
CA -> AC                (3)
CB -> BC                (4)
CV -> AV                (5)
DA -> AD                (6)
DB -> BD                (7)
DV -> BV                (8)
U  -> ε                 (9)
V  -> ε                 (10)
A  -> a                 (11)
B  -> b                 (12)

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: First I thought about some words, that are in the language: ε, 00, 11, 01,10,1010,1001 and tried to find a grammar:

Comment: @askleg 01, 10 and 1001 are not in L. Words in L are words like 101101 that consist of one word repeated twice.

Comment: Doesn't the "*" stand for epsilon, the word one time, or as often as you want?